# Determining the latitude/longitude view bounds in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have something very similar to this [D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2374239) with the difference being a single state instead of the entire country. I would like to extract the ["view bounds"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Ki9.png) in latitude/longitude after the user has zoomed in to a certain degree so that I can provide information back to them on that area.

It seems it would be some combination of:

- d3.geo.bounds/path.bounds (doesn't take zooming/panning into account)
- the SVG's translation/scale
- projection.invert?

I see a bunch of examples for lat/long points to cartesian space using the projection() function but nothing going in the other direction (e.g. clicking arbitrarily on a map -> lat/long, displaying lat/long of the center of the map which changes with zoom/pan, etc.)

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: I'm uncertain why this question has been marked as off-topic as I have included a) a link to a working example with source code and b) a graphical depiction of what I'm trying to accomplish in addition to an explanation above. What else is necessary?

Comment: Well "describe specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it **in the question itself**". It's nice to have the code you have tried so far also.

Answer (score 0):

D3 has the [`invert()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-invert) for this. It does exactly what you want it to do -- you pass it screen coordinates and it returns unprojected coordinates.

This function is a member of the projection, so as long as you're using the projection to do zoom/translate, you don't need to account for that explicitly. To get the corner points, you can simply take the center point (which you know because that's how you set the zoom) and the dimensions of the SVG.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm using the zoom/pan method shown in the link. It "can rapidly redraw geographic features while panning and zooming, without the overhead of reprojection", which means it transforms the SVG itself instead of modifying the projection. While it's good for performance, the projection object is unaware of how I've zoomed/panned so it can't tell me how to accurately invert by itself.